# What does the phrase "Bolting for the Door" mean?

Tags: phrases, idioms, meaning-in-context

I was watching [this video](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-4-quicksort-randomized-algorithms/) and at 41:05 secs the professor uses this phrase *Bolting for the Door* . Does it mean that students will get bored or it will be too difficult for the students such that they will be eager to go out as soon  as possible ?

P.S : Searching google for "bolt for the door" didn't provide encouraging answers.

The full context of the quote is:

> By the time we get to the end of this class you folks are going to be *bolting for the door* because we are going to do some good math today.  It's actually fun math, I think, but it is challenging.

Comment: One doesn’t search Google; one looks up the verb *bolt* in a dictionary.  Google is crap.

Comment: Either of your interpretations (too hard or bored) is perfectly consistent with the phrase *bolting for the door.*

Comment: @tchrist Google isn't crap, it can even direct you to some very lovely dictionaries!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bolt** as an intransitive verb means *to dash* or *to escape*. The professor means the (exhausted) students will be dashing towards the exit of the classroom as soon as he finishes, as he has had to teach an intensive lecture of math.

Comment: I like the "Garam Masala" description of your "About Me " :-) . Anyway +1 for the answer .

Answer (score 1):

In the same way the phrase "The horse has already bolted" means the horse made a sudden break or dash to escape and succeeded, the phrase detailed by the OP above indicates the students will be doing or attempting exactly the same.  I.E. making a break for freedom.  Good luck students, that's all I can say!

Answer (score 0):

"*Bolt*" is just "*bolt*" and it is defined by Merriam-Webster as:

```
to move suddenly or rapidly; to dash
```

But I think you already know this. What you are probably looking for is an interpretation of the phrase in the bigger context of the video.

Between your two choices, the second -- "*it will be too difficult for the students such that they will be eager to go out as soon as possible*" is closer to the truth.

The speaker in the video also gives a lot of clues that support this. For one, in your own quote -- *It's actually fun math, I think, but it is challenging* -- the word "**challenging**" is used to mean **difficult**.